# Creating Recurring Payments with Reference Transaction

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am having trouble with german users because I cannot use recurring payments. My scenario is to be able to set up a system where the users can be billed monthly or yearly depending on my needs. I contacted PayPal and they said I can do this using Reference Transaction.
I started implementing but so many question arised. My calls are like this:

Note: # fields are disabled but I played with them.
1. Call to get token to create billing agreement

```
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT': "0",
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE': "USD",
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC': "Daily_Subsription",
            'L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0': "Daily_Subsription",
            'L_BILLINGTYPE0': "MerchantInitiatedBilling",
            'CANCELURL': "http://192.168.100.10/paypal_express/",
            'RETURNURL': "http://192.168.100.10/paypal_express/",
            #'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION': 'Authorization',
            'CURRENCYCODE':'USD',
            'METHOD': "SetExpressCheckout",
```

Result:

```
    'ACK': 'Success',
    'TIMESTAMP': '2015-12-04T13:13:59Z',
    'TOKEN': 'EC-7LE96518YR0055319',
    'VERSION': '116.0',
    'BUILD': '18308778',
    'CORRELATIONID': '17681d6b20d48'
```

2. Create the billing agreement.

   ```
       'METHOD': "CreateBillingAgreement",
       'TOKEN': my_token, # token from SetExpressCheckout
   ```

Result:

```
    'ACK': 'Success',
    'TIMESTAMP': '2015-12-04T13:14:19Z', 
    'VERSION': '116.0',
    'BUILD': '18308778',
    'BILLINGAGREEMENTID': 'B-7H2153525D722501M',
    'CORRELATIONID': 'cca3843b1b9b1'
```

3. Create the recurring profile

   ```
       'TOKEN': my_token, # token from SetExpressCheckout
       'METHOD': 'CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile',
       'PROFILESTARTDATE': "2015-12-06T16:05:48Z",
       'BILLINGPERIOD': "Day",
       'BILLINGFREQUENCY': "1",
       'CURRENCYCODE':'USD',
       'AMT': "1.00",
       'PAYERID': PAYERID,
       #'INITAMT': "3.00",
       #'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION': 'sale',
       'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC': "Daily_Subsription",
       'DESC': "Daily_Subsription",
   ```

Result:

```
    'ACK': 'Success',
    'TIMESTAMP': '2015-12-04T13:14:21Z',
    'VERSION': '116.0',
    'BUILD': '000000',
    'PROFILEID': 'B-7H2153525D722501M',
    'CORRELATIONID': '8ecf29d5a1059'
```

Now it really makes me wonder what should happen and why is not working, because the profile ID is returned but no PROFILESTATUS or even TRANSACTIONID is returned.

Waiting for input or a better flow explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the DoReferenceTransaction API using the billing agreement ID an specifying the Recurring variable to Y. But in before that when creating the billing agreement ID, you must have established a billing agreement with the buyer specifying the amount, frequency, and duration of the recurring payment. You can refer here for documentation.

Is there any issue if during the SetExpressCheckout you specify the billing type to Recurring Payment? Any error would appear?

Comment: I need this to work without credit card linked to PayPal so if I specify the billing type to RecurringPayment on SetExpressCheckout it does not let me continue and says "We cannot procceed the request. Please got back to the store an chose another option". I am testing this using Sandbox german accounts with only bank accounts linked.

Comment: Unfortunately that for Germany user/customer they need to use the credit card as there are no direct debits is currently possible. Since you are using billing agreement, you may need to recharge them using reference transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Reference Transactions and Recurring Payments are entirely separate things.  While you can technically use the two together in a single checkout, that wouldn't be a typical scenario.

In your case you've got everything correct with the $0 authorization and the creation of the billing agreement.  You would not make another call to CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile, though.  You would simply save the billing agreement ID in your customer's record in your database.

You would then have to build your own recurring system, basically.  You would have a script that runs every day (or however often you want) on your server and processes any payments that are due that day.

As it loops through these due payments, it pulls the billing agreement ID for each one, and uses it in a [DoReferenceTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) API call to process the amount you need to process.

So using CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile would create the profile in PayPal's system so that you can rely on them to run those payments for every day instead of building that part yourself.  Apparently you have a limitation with that, though, which is why they're telling you need to use ref. transactions instead.

Just to answer those questions, though, the reason you did not get a transaction ID back here is because no payment actually occurred. The transaction was simply the creation of a profile, and you did get the profile ID back.  Only when payments are processed against a profile would you then get a transaction ID for that specific payment.

Again, though, in your case you need to not worry about CRPP at all and just work with reference transactions.